# Saving data for multiple items while navigating through list of items

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am new this type of c++/cli language and i look for some help. I develop a project about the ListBoxes, i got some codes and learn basic steps on it. But i am actually stuck on the hardest part in this project.

The project counts framenumbers and keeps it. Its just an integer number and i got next and previous buttons in my code. when people click somewhere in the image, gui gets x and y coordinates and write it to the listbox correctly. What i trying to do is, when people push the next button, framenumber increased by one and clear listbox interface and ready for get other x and y coordinates. When people pressed previous button, ListBox should show the previous framenumbers x and y coordinates.

My question is, can i keep this x and y data in somewhere and reach at will? What should i do for keep these data? Any helps or thoughts will be appreciated for me.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: I've retitled the question, to more align with what you're actually asking. If you're actually looking for help with listboxes & Windows Forms, please either edit the question to be more specific to that, or post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create a class to hold the data you want to save for each frame, and stick it into a collection of some sort as the user navigates through the frames. You could keep a List or a Stack, to implement retrieving the 'previous' item, but I'd probably use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). Make the key of the dictionary the frame number, and have the value be the class of data you're saving for each frame.

Perhaps something like this:

```
public ref class FrameData
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    FrameData(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};

Dictionary<int, FrameData^>^ savedFrameData = gcnew Dictionary<int, FrameData^>();

// When they click the next or previous button:

// Save the data for the old frame.
savedFrameData->[oldFrameNumber] = gcnew FrameData(currentX, currentY);

// Retrieve the previous data for the new frame, if found.
FrameData^ dataForNewFrame;
if (savedFrameData->TryGetValue(newFrameNumber, dataForNewFrame))
{
    currentX = dataForNewFrame->x;
    currentY = dataForNewFrame->y;
}
else
{
    currentX = 0;
    currentY = 0;
}
```